# Azure Oauth 2 unable to map all claims payload jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I am trying to create an asp.net core 3.1 api with oauth 2. The authentication/authorization is all good by this piece of code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "AzureAD";
            })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddOAuth("AzureAD", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["AppSettings:AzureAuthentication:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AppSettings:AzureAuthentication:ClientSecret"];
                    //options.ClientSecret = _appSettings.AzureAuthentication.ClientSecret;
                    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth");
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    //options.Scope.Add("user.read");
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx-5ceb-4dcc-9c08-xxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
                    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx-5ceb-4dcc-9c08-xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo";

                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    // Specify how to map the claims from the jwt 
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("EmailAddresss", "email");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("Username", "unique_name");


                    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
                    {
                        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                        {
                            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                            var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).RootElement;
                            context.RunClaimActions(user);
                        }
                    };
                });
```

With success i can intercept the accesstoken and decode it online confirm it has this payload:

```
"aud": "00000003-0000000-000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/",
  "iat": 15772157,
  "nbf": 5545,
  "exp": 15776057,
  "acct": 1,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "xxxxAu/8xxxxxx+qmbSExxxxxE8QkIRLdeFfPay244p/Zrzxxxxxr/eYnxxxxxkm/AOxxxxug==",
  "altsecid": "5::100xxxxx9E"
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "Displayname",
  "appid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "email": "fake@hotmail.com",
  "idp": "https://stds.winddga.net/a3b390fds7c2434dbd69/",
  "ipaddr": "255.255.255.255",
  "name": "john, doe",
  "oid": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "xxxxxxxx",
  "scp": "openid User.Read profile email",
  "sub": "JFYa_zXr8z2hxXPu87hmLa_yMUyewLxVGJCGUsPfZqo",
  "tid": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
  "unique_name": "Unique_name@hotmail.com",
  "uti": "xxxxx",
  "ver": "1.0",

}
```

In the controller i am trying to display all these claims from the payload.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            var claims = User.Claims.Select(x => new { Type = x.Type.Split('/').LastOrDefault(), Value =  x.Value}).ToList();
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(claims);
        }
```

the user (claimsprincipal) only contains 4 claims (far less than i would expect).

So i know the claims are in the payload but i am not able to access them appart from decoding the jwt. I would expect options.ClaimActions.MapAll() would map alle the claims but it is only mapping four. If i try: options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("EmailAddresss", "email") it will map the email claim but this does not work with: options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("Username", "unique_name").

Question:
How do i access all the data (claims in my understanding) in my controller apart from picture name and mail?

EDIT: What i just realized: It is setting the claims from the userinformation endpoint and not the jwt. I can decode the jwt in the controller ofc but i dont think that would be the solution. Isn't the accesstoken already decoded somewhere to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to use `AddOAuth` will acquire Microsoft Graph's access token and get user's profile from Microsoft Graph's UserInfo endpoint , so it will only map claims from Microsoft Graph's UserInfo endpoint . You can directly  query `/me` to obtain user information using Microsoft Graph API and add to user principle :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Another way is using `AddOpenIdConnect` Middleware which will read claims from ID token and OIDC's UserInfo endpoint which give more user's profile information :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

A simple way is to use the default Azure AD template : Change Authentication --> `Work or School Accounts` when creating the asp.net core web application .

Comment: I will try to implement it soon and let you know, Another middleware looks like a good startingpoint.

Comment: Addopenidconnect is the way to go. This way i got all the claims from the id_token. Thanks for your direction